# I'm having trouble printing a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to open a file and store it's contents as a variable. It feels like this should be really simple but I am not getting what I want.
This is my code:

```
file = str(input('enter a file name to decipher: '))
DAta = open(file,'r')
print(DAta.read)
```

And I thought that this would just print out my file. But I keep getting this:

```
<built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x03044E30>
```

I could really use some help and fast. thanks a bunch!

Comment: `read` is a method, so call it.  `print(DAta.read())`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `read` method, which is done by following it with parentheses.  Without them, it is simply a bound method.  So use:

```
print(DAta.read())
```

Also, it's a good idea to close a file when you're done accessing it:

```
DAta.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

@abby call read method by including round paranthesis like this read(), you should print content of your file like this DAta.read() and after reading the content of file, always make a habit of closing the file with close() method DAta.close().

Answer (score 0):

read is a **method** from File class, so you must add ()

```
DAta.read()
```